# Sort string array containing time in format '09:00 AM'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort my array.

The array consists of data in time format.

Array:

```
'9:15 AM', '10:20 AM', '02:15 PM'
```

How should I sort it ?

I'm getting this data usig json service & using it to list events in jquery mobile's listview . but I want to sort events by time .

**UPDATE:
HOW I SORTED DATA FROM JSON BY BOTH DATE AND TIME:**

For my particular problem of sorting data got using json by date & time I done like this :

```
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'read.php?month_no='+month_no, function(data) {


        events = data.data;

        events.sort(function(a,b){
            a = new Date(a.event_date+' '+a.event_time);
            b = new Date(b.event_date+' '+b.event_time);
            return a<b?-1:a>b?1:0;
       });


});
```

Comment: I would split the collection in 2 arrays : 1 with AM strings, 1 with PM strings, then order them separately and display them 1 after each other.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this

```
var times = ['01:00 am', '06:00 pm', '12:00 pm', '03:00 am', '12:00 am'];

times.sort(function (a, b) {
  return new Date('1970/01/01 ' + a) - new Date('1970/01/01 ' + b);
});

console.log(times);
```

Comment: This is working just as I wanted . Thanks . 
I didn't thought to compare using Date object .

Comment: but can you tell you how I use this for sorting data got using json .

 $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'read.php?month_no='+month_no, function(data) {
 
  events = data.data;

there is events[].event_date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format and
events[].event_time in above givent format

Answer (score 11):

My solution (For times formated like "11:00", "16:30"..)

```
sortTimes: function (array) {
    return array.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (parseInt(a.split(":")[0]) - parseInt(b.split(":")[0]) === 0) {
            return parseInt(a.split(":")[1]) - parseInt(b.split(":")[1]);
        } else {
            return parseInt(a.split(":")[0]) - parseInt(b.split(":")[0]);
        }
    })
}
```

In case someone wanted to know haha

Answer (score 6):

Implement the [sort(compare)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function and compare the date string using any arbitrary date :

```
Array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return Date.parse('01/01/2013 '+a) - Date.parse('01/01/2013 '+b)
});
```

*01/01/2013* is any arbitrary date.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = ['9:15 AM', '10:20 AM', '02:15 PM'];

var sort = function(a){
  var sa = [],
      d = new Date(),
      ds = d.toDateString();

  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    d = new Date(ds + ' ' + a[i]);
    sa.push(d);
  }

  sa.sort(function(a, b){return a.getTime() - b.getTime();})
  return sa;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortTimes(arrayOfTimes) {

    return arrayOfTimes.sort((a, b) => {
        const aParts = getNumericParts(a);
        const bParts = getNumericParts(b);

        // Sorts by hour then minute
        return aParts[0] - bParts[0] || aParts[1] - bParts[1];
    });

    function getNumericParts(time) {
        // accounts formats of 9:15 AM and 09:15:30 but does not handle AM/PM in comparison
        return time.split(' ')[0].split(':').map(x => +x);
    }
}
```

Here's a more concise and performant variation of Dustin Silk's answer. It takes into account formats of 9:15 AM, 09:15, and 09:15:30 though it does not sort based on seconds. You could add that by using `|| aParts[2] - bParts[2]` as a part of the return statement.

```
sortTimes(['08:00', '09:00', '05:00', '08:15', '08:00']) 
// Output ["05:00", "08:00", "08:00", "08:15", "09:00"]
```