# How to sort array of objects by time string value?

Tags: javascript, sorting, date

I have an array of objects like so :

```
var example = [{
  "description": "aaa",
  "time": "12:15pm"
}, {
  "description": "bbb",
  "time": "10:10am"
}, {
  "description": "ccc",
  "time": "4:00pm"
}, {
  "description": "ddd",
  "time": "6:15pm"
}, {
  "description": "eee",
  "time": "1:10am"
}, {
  "description": "fff",
  "time": "5:00pm"
} ];
```

I want to sort by the `time` value.

I have tried to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17064665/1063287) which was intended for an array of string values:

```
example.sort(function (a, b) {
  return new Date('1970/01/01 ' + a.time) - new Date('1970/01/01 ' + b.time);
});

console.log(example);
```

I've also been referring to the Mozilla [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) documentation and tried the following which didn't seem to work:

```
example.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (new Date(a.time) > new Date(b.time)) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (new Date(a.time) < new Date(b.time)) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
});

console.log(example);
```

Comment: Your issue is that is not a valid date format to be parsed.

Comment: `new Date("1:10am"); //Invalid Date`

Comment: I will try with space before am/pm suffix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The date string that you are generating is not valid so it will always returns current date and time. So generate valid date string(eg : `'1970/01/01 9:34:48 AM'`) then parse and return the difference. Here **[`String#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** method can be used to generate the valid date string.

```js
var example = [{
  "description": "aaa",
  "time": "12:15pm"
}, {
  "description": "bbb",
  "time": "10:10am"
}, {
  "description": "ccc",
  "time": "4:00pm"
}, {
  "description": "ddd",
  "time": "6:15pm"
}, {
  "description": "eee",
  "time": "1:10am"
}, {
  "description": "fff",
  "time": "5:00pm"
}];

example.sort(function(a, b) {
  // get time from string 
  // then get am or pm from string and append
  // both can be done using the slice method
  return Date.parse('1970/01/01 ' + a.time.slice(0, -2) + ' ' + a.time.slice(-2)) - Date.parse('1970/01/01 ' + b.time.slice(0, -2) + ' ' + b.time.slice(-2))
});

console.log(example);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `space` before `am/pm` to make valid date .

We can put it in sort method before comparing as below.

```
example.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date('1970/01/01 ' + a.time.replace(/(am|pm)/,' $1'))
 - new Date('1970/01/01 ' + b.time.replace(/(am|pm)/,' $1'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate value in 24hr format and sort it accordingly.

#### Logic:

1. Check if `pm`  exists in string
2. If yes and hour is not `12`, add 12 to it
3. Else return the number

```js
var example=[{description:"aaa",time:"12:15pm"},{description:"bbb",time:"10:10am"},{description:"ccc",time:"4:00pm"},{description:"ddd",time:"6:15pm"},{description:"eee",time:"1:10am"},{description:"fff",time:"5:00pm"}];

example.sort(function(a,b){
  var t1 = get24HrFormat(a.time);
  var t2 = get24HrFormat(b.time);
  return t1>t2 ? 1 : t1<t2 ? -1 : 0;
});

function get24HrFormat(str){
  var _t = str.split(/[^0-9]/g);
  _t[0] =+_t[0] + (str.indexOf("pm")>-1 && +_t[0]!==12 ? 12: 0);
  return _t.join("");
}
  
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(example,0,4)+ "</pre>")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your time to hours and minutes (hours should be in 24-hour format) you don't even need to use the `Date` constructor.

Something like this:

```
example.map(c => {
  var time = c.time.substring(0,c.time.length - 2);
  var am_pm = c.time.slice(-2);

  var hours = parseInt(time.split(':')[0]);
  var minutes = parseInt(time.split(':')[1]);

  if (hours === 12 && am_pm.toLowerCase() === 'am') {
    hours = 0;
  } else if (hours < 12 && am_pm.toLowerCase() === 'pm') {
    hours += 12;
  }

  // save hours and minutes
  c.hours = hours;
  c.minutes = minutes;

  return c;
}).sort((a,b) => {
  return (a.hours * 100 + a.minutes) - (b.hours * 100 + b.minutes); 
});
```

Note, this modifies the `examples` array by adding `hours` and `minutes` properties.