# Sort array object using time

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array of objects like this:

```
arr = [
  { id: '5', Time: '01:00', status: 'grey'  },
  { id: '7', Time: '12:00', status: 'grey'  },
  { id: '8', Time: '12:45', status: 'green' },
]
```

Result I'm trying to get like this:

```
[
  { id: '7', Time: '12:00', status: 'grey'  },
  { id: '8', Time: '12:45', status: 'green' },
  { id: '5', Time: '01:00', status: 'grey'  },
]
```

I am doing sort like this but not working:

```
arr = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
  var a1 = a.Time;
  var b1 = b.Time;
  if (a1 == b1) return 0;
  return a1 > b1 ? 1 : -1;
});
```

While debug I noticed for example `arr[0].Time >  arr[1].Time` gives me `false`, but `"1:00" > "12:00"` gives me `true`.

My debug console is below.

[image: ConsoleLog]

I am using Chrome and Firefox and both giving same results. Any idea?

Comment: What output were you expecting instead? 01:00 followed by 12:00 followed by 12:45 looks to be in order

Comment: `"1:00" > "12:00"` isn't what's in the object. `"01:00" > "12:00"` is false.

Comment: @CertainPerformance i m trying to sort like this "12:00" then "12:45" then "01:00"

Comment: @evolutionxbox can u suggest solution bcz i trying to sort array of object to get the result like this:

 [       {id: '7', Time: '12:00', status: 'grey'},
         {id: '8', Time: '12:45', status: 'green'},
{id: '5', Time: '01:00', status: 'grey'},]

Comment: Where would a time of 10:00 come, then? At the very beginning (before 12), or at the end (after 01:00)? Sounds weird...

Comment: @CertainPerformance i ve most times are of PM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort array of objects by time string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702849/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-by-time-string-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert them to a Date object.

```
const birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')    // change 03:24
```

Then you can compare two dates.
in one go

```js
arr = [{
    id: '5',
    Time: '01:00',
    status: 'grey'
  },
  {
    id: '7',
    Time: '12:00',
    status: 'grey'
  },
  {
    id: '8',
    Time: '12:45',
    status: 'green'
  },

]

arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  var date1 = (new Date("2000-01-01T" + a.Time + ":00")).getTime()
  var date2 = (new Date("2000-01-01T" + b.Time + ":00")).getTime()
  return (date1 < date2 ? -1 : (date1 > date2 ? 1 : 0))
  
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say all of these times are in PM, 12-hour notation is not zero-based (12, 1, 2, ... 11). It's probably easiest to convert these times to a zero-based notation, in which case `00:00` and `00:45` both come before `01:00`.

To achieve this we can simply take the remainder of the hours if we divide it by 12.

```
const zeroBasedHour = hour % 12; // 0-11, instead of 12, 1-11
```

Let's create a function that does the conversion and adds the minutes in decimal form.

```
// 12-hour notation without am/pm.
// The initial 0 in 03:45 is optional.
function decimalTime(timeNotation) {
  const [, hours, minutes] = timeNotation.match(/^(\d?\d):(\d\d)$/);

  return parseInt(hours, 10) % 12
       + parseInt(minutes, 10) / 60;
}
```

This function would convert `12:00` to the decimal value `0`. `12:45` is converted to the decimal value `0.75`. And `01:00` is converted into `1`. This makes sorting the array based on time alone very easy.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: '5', Time: '01:00', status: 'grey'  },
  { id: '7', Time: '12:00', status: 'grey'  },
  { id: '8', Time: '12:45', status: 'green' },
];

arr.sort((a, b) => decimalTime(a.Time) - decimalTime(b.Time));
console.log(arr);

function decimalTime(timeNotation) {
  const [, hours, minutes] = timeNotation.match(/^(\d?\d):(\d\d)$/);

  return parseInt(hours, 10) % 12
       + parseInt(minutes, 10) / 60;
}
```

Note that the above assumes times are all either AM or PM, but not a mix of the two. You can very easily add AM/PM support by adding an additional 12 to final value if the provided time is PM. Do note that the function below no longer accepts a time without AM/PM.

```
// 12-hour notation with am/pm.
// The initial 0 in 03:45 is optional.
// The space between the time and am/pm is also optional.
// am/pm is case insensitive.
function decimalTime(timeNotation) {
  const modifiers = { am: 0, pm: 12 };

  const [, hours, minutes, modifier] =
    timeNotation.match(/^(\d?\d):(\d\d) ?(am|pm)?$/i);

  return parseInt(hours, 10) % 12
       + modifiers[modifier.toLowerCase()]
       + parseInt(minutes, 10) / 60;
}
```