# Loop through times and dates and display latest at top with EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Hello I have an app that uses express, ejs and mongodb. In my app I have a reporting page that shows the time and date the report was created. Right now it shows the newest on the bottom. I want it to always be the first report.

The data for start time and date are being stored in a local instance of MongoDB. I use a route to find all reports from the collection and call upon the data using ejs.

For example I have two reports with a date format of 3-27-2018. The latest time is 2:32:16 PM and the earliest is 1:59:13 PM. So I loop through the data with ejs to get all the data per report but how can I loop through just the time and date and than show the latest at the top.

This is just the snippet of code where date and time live

```
 <% wssresults.forEach(function(results){ %>
     <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <%
                  var t = results.start_time;
                  var d = results.start_date;
                  %>

                  <p>Time: <span class="startTime"><%= t %></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <p>Date: <span class="startDate"><%= d %></span></p>
                </div>
              </div>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Before your `forEach`, you can run a `sort` on your array ( `wssresults.sort(dateCompare).forEach`) where `dateCompare(a,b)` would employ one of the methods listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064603/sort-string-array-containing-time-in-format-0900-am

Comment: Or perform your "latest time" logic directly in your mongo query (or in your route) and pass the latest time to your template.

Comment: Thanks @jmcgriz, just adding .sort() brought the most recent report to the top of the list. I have another report page that it did not work for though, maybe because of how it is stored in the DB..Im looking into whats different. For the most part both reports have the same type of data and format with some minor differences.